# Dynamic assignment to class variables

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

So I'm using a function to stop having to Copy+Pasta code everywhere which has the exact same use minus the error messages I want the exception to display, but I want to be able to access and set class variables dynamically for Django parsing.

For example:
I know that if you feed vars()['{}'.format(a_variable)] as long as the variable is named you can access it. But how do you do this for instances?
Code below doesn't work, but outlines what I would like to achieve if there is a vars() like function for instances or a random about way/better way of doing this:

```
class test(object):
    max_length = 10
    text = 'blah'
    name = 'hrrrnngg'

    def set_name(self, text):
        self.name = self._parse_text(text, 'name')

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.text = self._parse_text(text, 'text')

    def _parse_text(self, data, variable):
        # a simple idea, but much exception coding in here, i.e. negatives, ranges e.t.c.
        if len(data) + len(vars()['self.{}'.format(variable)]) > self.max_length:
            print "You have failed this city"
        else:
            return "{}, {}".format(vars()['self.{}'.format(variable)], data)

a = test()
print a.text
a.set_text('moo')
print a.text
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for [`getattr(self, variable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)?

Comment: I will take that as a yes!

Comment: See corrected code :) Much helpfulness when parsing is 20LOCs repeated per item being set haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe
The corrected code is:

```
class test(object):
    max_length = 10
    name = 'batman'
    text = 'blah'

    def set_name(self, text):
        self.name = self._parse_text(text, 'name')

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.text = self._parse_text(text, 'text')

    def _parse_text(self, data, variable):
        if len(data) + len(getattr(self, str(variable))) > self.max_length:
            print "You have failed this city"
            return getattr(self, str(variable))
        else:
            return getattr(self, str(variable)) + data


a = test()
print a.text
a.set_text('moo')
print a.text
a.set_text('derppphard')
print a.text
```

This code prints to console:

```
$ blah
$ blahmoo
$ You have failed this city
$ blahmoo
```

Comment: There's really no point to `'{}'.format(variable)` - all of your examples are already strings (and if not just use `str(variable)`).

Comment: Edited :) 
Thanks heaps! Such a handy little tool to know!

Comment: It's not really an answer, but I wrote a more Pythonic version for you to have a look at: https://gist.github.com/textbook/c58450994506d565b7c1

Comment: Well.. It kind of is.. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can give you credit? :3